# Formatting phone number without knowing locale

Tags: java, formatting, i18n

I am trying to format supplied phone numbers for a web application.  Users in general will be supplying US-based phone numbers, but it is possible for some users to input a phone number from another country.

Here are my assumptions:

- Default to US if the number of digits is 7 or 10 after stripping non-digits.  If not, just return the String
- Use tested external
  libraries where possible since speed isn't an utmost concern (the
  service can be run in the background if it is really that slow).
- Prefer an external library over a custom regex.

For the first assumption, I am thinking that if there is another country that has phone numbers with 7 or 10 digits, it's not the end of the world to have it formatted in US format.

Here's my code anyway, using Google's libphonenumber:

```
public static String formatPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, Locale locale) throws NumberParseException {
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber usNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, locale.getCountry());
    return phoneUtil.format(usNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
}

public static String formatUSPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) throws NumberParseException {

    //First strip out any non-digits
    phoneNumber = stripNonDigits(phoneNumber);

    phoneNumber = (phoneNumber == null) ? BaseConstants.EMPTY_STRING : phoneNumber;
    if ((phoneNumber.length() != 7) && (phoneNumber.length() != 10)) {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    return formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, Locale.US);
}
```

I am adding this method to be comprehensive, but it's not directly needed for review (credit to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031040/192465)):

```
public static String stripNonDigits(final CharSequence input){
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        final char c = input.charAt(i);
        if(c > 47 && c < 58){
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The associated `JUnit` tests:

```
@Test
public void testFormatPhoneNumber() throws NumberParseException {
  assertEquals(FormUtils.formatPhoneNumber("2122222222", Locale.US), "(212) 222-2222");
  assertEquals(FormUtils.formatPhoneNumber("2122222222", Locale.CANADA), "(212) 222-2222");
  assertEquals(FormUtils.formatPhoneNumber("(021)11111111", Locale.GERMANY), "0211 1111111");
}

@Test
public void testFormatUSPhoneNumber() throws NumberParseException {
  assertEquals(FormUtils.formatUSPhoneNumber("2122222222"), "(212) 222-2222");
  assertEquals(FormUtils.formatUSPhoneNumber("92122222222"), "92122222222");
  assertEquals(FormUtils.formatUSPhoneNumber("(212)2222222"), "(212) 222-2222");
  assertEquals(FormUtils.formatUSPhoneNumber("(212)222-2222"), "(212) 222-2222");
  assertEquals(FormUtils.formatUSPhoneNumber("(212) 222-2222"), "(212) 222-2222");
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Are there tests I should add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some improvements...

**Variable re-assignment and `null`-check**

You are re-assigning `phoneNumber` twice, and unfortunately I think you don't even need it at all.

First, it's generally not a nice idea to re-assign the method argument because careless mistakes may result in you inadvertently changing the instance referenced by it somewhere inside the method, when you're expecting the *original* input. Even if you don't explicitly `final` method parameters, it's simpler to always treat method arguments as an invariant so that you know what the method is processing *on/with*. Therefore, you should simply assign the output of `stripNonDigits()` to a new variable, and you can inline the new variable in the subsequent calls:

```
public static String formatPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) throws NumberParseException {
    String strippedNumber = stripNonDigits(phoneNumber);
    return strippedNumber.length() != 7 && strippedNumber.length() != 10 ?
                strippedNumber : formatAsUSPhoneNumber(strippedNumber);
}
```

Now, you don't need a `null`-check (it's not in the right place anyways - it should be done at the start), and I renamed the main method as `formatAsUSPhoneNumber()`. I feel that `formatUSPhoneNumber()` is suggesting that it is formatting a US phone number into another representation.

**`stripNonDigits()`**

If `stripNonDigits()` should be used only by `formatAsPhoneNumber()`, consider making them `private static`. Ok, so even if you prefer not to use regex (fair point), how about [`Character.isDigit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-)? I feel that it's easier to read than the condition you have, short of the one-liner regex:

```
// replace all non-digits with an empty String
return input.toString().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

Comment: From the post on SO, Character.isDigit() allows certain other characters other than 0-9: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29.  Good point about making the method private and using the word "As."  I otherwise reworded the methods in my question to be a little more representative of what I am doing.  And you're right, the null check should be in the beginning.

Comment: Are you concerned about non-UTF-8/'ASCII' characters?

Comment: Yes, I've been through that issue before.  It's not particularly fun.

Comment: Ok, now your implementation makes sense. :)